# Angular5, show spinner icon on load of angular app at Main page

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am trying to show the spinner icon in the center when we load the angular app login page

Below is my index.html code for an angular app

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <base href="./">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


    </head>
    <body>
<style>
    .container{
        height:100%;
    }
    html, body {
        height:100%;
    }
 </style>

    <angular-app>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
                <div class="w-25 mx-auto">  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw loading-icon"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </angular-app>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Spinner icon comes on hard refresh, not on normal refresh, but if I use some text like loading then it will come even on normal refresh. Also, I was trying to center the spinner, it's coming on hard refresh but on the left side, I don't want to use any CSS, trying to center it using bootstrap

Comment: At first you need to load bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">




................................................I added this link but no change

Comment: Also you need add fontawesome https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css

Comment: thanks, it works now, but i give class text-center, it works only with hard refresh

Comment: He doesn't need bootstrap. He only needs fontawesome

Comment: How to center the div without using css ?

Answer (score -1):

The most simple way is to use **pace.js**

https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Pace will automatically monitor your ajax requests, event loop lag, document ready state, and elements on your page to decide the progress. On ajax navigation it will begin again!

For a fast start just add a library to your project and add to your Index.html:

```
<head>
  <script src="/pace/pace.js"></script>
  <link href="/pace/themes/pace-theme-barber-shop.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```